# How to change argument of function passed as reference?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a promise chain here and I'm passing a reference to a function and arguments get passed to it.
When we get to the 6th `.then()` we throw an error. I want that `Error` in the format of `Error.message` so I get the text `OH NOES` instead of the actual error.
I could do this in the alwaysThrows function of course and I also could pass a function to the method, e.g. `Catch(function(error) { return error.message})`. But I was wondering if there is a way to manipulate the argument passed to console.log withouy passing a function to it but keeping it just as an reference to `console.log` ?

```
function alwaysThrows() {
    throw new Error('OH NOES');
}
function iterate(num){ 
    console.log(num)
    return num + 1;
}
promise = Promise.resolve(1)
.then(iterate) // 1
.then(iterate) // 2
.then(iterate) // 3
.then(iterate) // 4
.then(iterate) // 5
.then(alwaysThrows)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.catch(console.log)
```

Comment: You want to change the value passed to `console.log`, but without changing the input value passed to `console.log` as in `.catch(error => Promise.reject(error.message))`? No, that’s not possible. Seems pretty arbitrary as a restriction, too.

Comment: `.catch(error => console.log(error.toString()))`

Comment: @Ryan yes, I thought there might be some solution with .call or .bind and/or some weird argument destructuring. Curious.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a generic function to handle the error.

Here I've created a simple function called `niceLog`, & placed this into the catch callback.

The `e.message || e.toString()` just makes it so it says  `OH NOES` else it will say `Error: OH NOES`, if there is no message property it will fall back to toString.

```js
function niceLog(e) {
  console.log(e.message || e.toString());
}

function alwaysThrows() {
    throw new Error('OH NOES');
}
function iterate(num){ 
    console.log(num)
    return num + 1;
}
promise = Promise.resolve(1)
.then(iterate) // 1
.then(iterate) // 2
.then(iterate) // 3
.then(iterate) // 4
.then(iterate) // 5
.then(alwaysThrows)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.then(iterate)
.catch(niceLog)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works too! Was more looking for a way without passing an actual function to it but manipulating the argument, but I understand now javascript doesn't have a way for it. Knowing what javascript can't do is also nice to know :-).